# gdb ignores my breakpoints and more

Tags: debugging, gdb

I have a situation where I set a breakpoint in gdb, but doesn't have any affect and the program continues to run.

If I run the program normally from shell, eventually it prints something at the syslog (line 483).

So, I run the same program in gdb, I set a breakpoint at this line (483) and hit run, but instead of stopping at this line, the program continues to run until the end.

```
...
Reading symbols from /usr/src/scannedonly-0.21/src/scannedonlyd_clamav...done.
(gdb) b 483
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804a8f1: file scannedonlyd_clamav.c, line 483.
(gdb) run -n
Starting program: /usr/src/scannedonly-0.21/src/scannedonlyd_clamav
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
HAVE_LIBCLAMAV_CL_INIT: 1
main
mark
mark2
mark3
about to load_engine()
load_engine()
LibClamAV Error: Can't load /usr/local/share/clamav/daily.cvd: Can't allocate memory

Program exited with code 02.
(gdb)
```

Here is the part of the source:

```
 469 static struct cl_engine *load_engine()
 ...
 480         cl_engine_set_num(tmp, CL_ENGINE_MAX_SCANSIZE, (long long) 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 5);
 481         cl_engine_set_num(tmp, CL_ENGINE_MAX_FILESIZE, (long long) 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 5);
 482         if ((ret = cl_load(cl_retdbdir(), tmp, &sigs, CL_DB_STDOPT)) != CL_SUCCESS) {
 483                 syslog(LOG_CRIT, "WARNING2: Loading ClamAV database failed: %s", cl_strerror(ret));
 484                 cl_engine_free(tmp);
 485                 return NULL;
```

If I set a breakpoint to function load_engine(), it looks like it sets a breakpoint to another source file.

The good news is that it stops at the breakpoint, but then it's like it runs within a block-comment (lines 493, 497):

```
Reading symbols from /usr/src/scannedonly-0.21/src/scannedonlyd_clamav...done.
(gdb) b load_engine
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80496f7: file /usr/include/bits/stdio2.h, line 105.
(gdb) run -n
Starting program: /usr/src/scannedonly-0.21/src/scannedonlyd_clamav -n
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
HAVE_LIBCLAMAV_CL_INIT: 1
main
mark
mark2
mark3
about to load_engine()

Breakpoint 1, load_engine () at /usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:105
105       return __printf_chk (__USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1, __fmt, __va_arg_pack ());
(gdb) n
493     #else
(gdb) n
105       return __printf_chk (__USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1, __fmt, __va_arg_pack ());
(gdb) n
load_engine()
497             }
(gdb) list
492     /*
493     #else
494             if ((ret = cl_load(cl_retdbdir(), &tmp, &sigs, CL_DB_STDOPT))) {
495                     syslog(LOG_CRIT, "WARNING: Loading ClamAV database failed: %s", cl_strerror(ret));
496                     return NULL;
497             }
498             if ((ret = cl_build(tmp))) {
499                     syslog(LOG_CRIT, "WARNING: Building ClamAV engine failed: %s", cl_strerror(ret));
500                     cl_free(tmp);
501                     return NULL;
```

If I set a breakpoint at another line (1200) in main(), it stops at the correct line but on hitting next, the program flow skips lines.
It goes from line 1200 to 1208 on a single "next", although it shouldn't (i'm posting a "list" so you can also see the source):

```
Reading symbols from /usr/src/scannedonly-0.21/src/scannedonlyd_clamav...done.
(gdb) b 1200
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804b97e: file scannedonlyd_clamav.c, line 1200.
(gdb) run -n
Starting program: /usr/src/scannedonly-0.21/src/scannedonlyd_clamav -n
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
HAVE_LIBCLAMAV_CL_INIT: 1
main
mark
mark2
mark3

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0xbffff794) at scannedonlyd_clamav.c:1200
1200    #endif
(gdb) list
1195    #ifdef HAVE_LIBCLAMAV_CL_INIT
1196            if (cl_init(CL_INIT_DEFAULT) != CL_SUCCESS) {
1197                    syslog(LOG_CRIT, "ABORT, failed to initialize libclamav");
1198                    exit(3);
1199            }
1200    #endif
1201            DEBUG_MSG("about to load_engine()\n");
1202            engine[0] = load_engine();
1203            engine[1] = NULL;
1204            current_engine = 0;
(gdb) n
1208            }
(gdb) list
1203            engine[1] = NULL;
1204            current_engine = 0;
1205            if (engine[0] == NULL) {
1206                    syslog(LOG_CRIT, "ABORT, exiting: no clam engine");
1207                    exit(2);
1208            }
1209            memset(&dbstat, 0, sizeof(struct cl_stat));
1210            cl_statinidir(cl_retdbdir(), &dbstat);
1211    #ifndef HAVE_LIBCLAMAV_CL_INIT
1212            memset(&limits, 0, sizeof(struct cl_limits));
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Any ideas?

Btw, "run -n" is just an argument of the program to print msgs in console.

Comment: It looks like your source code and program are not in sync (e.g. some changes in code, but no recompilation of program). Try recompiling (i.e. `make clean && make`).

Comment: That's what I had thought at the beginning, but didn't make any difference. Same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem after all was the \r characters in the source.
Removing them solves the problem.